# How does event.stopImmediatePropagation work in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling

All pertinent code is posted below. I have a dice-based combat system. After the dice are rolled, an event called enableAttacks will enable any attacks that are allowed by the current dice (different combinations create different attacks). At the moment, I am taking a few shortcuts for testing, such as only enabling one attack and automatically selecting it as the chosen attack.

Here is the problem. The SetDice method gets called by a listener listening for MouseEvent.Click. This event takes the current state of the dice and passes it to the attackers enableAttack method. After it does that, it adds a listener to launch the chosen attack. (AFter I get this working, there will actually be another step in between, but that doesn't affect this test). However, even though I am calling stopImmediatePropagation on the MouseEvent, it is still triggering the second listener. According to the docs, stopImmediatePropagation

```
"Prevents processing of any event listeners in the current node and any subsequent nodes in the event flow. This method takes effect immediately, and it affects event listeners in the current node"
```

but the event is still triggering an eventListener added after the event is stopped. Clearly, my understanding of how this works in incorrect. What exactly does stopImmediatePropagation do, and if it doesn't do what I think it does, how can I get the added eventListener not to fire from the first event?

```
private function setDice(e:Event):void {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        currentDice = (e.target as HeroDice);
        trace(char1);
        attacker = char1;
        trace(currentDice);
        trace(attacker);
        attacker.enableAttacks(currentDice);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, launchAttack);
    }

public function enableAttacks(dice:HeroDice):void {
        if (dice.getPower() > 2) {
            trace("attack enabled");
            portrait.alpha -= .1;
        }
    }

public function launchAttack(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //make sure that e.target is character first
        if(attacker != null && e.target != null && (e.target as Character) != attacker){
            var target:Character = (e.target as Character);
            attacker.attack(target);
            attacker = null;
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, launchAttack);
        }

    }

public function attack(target:Character):void {
        switch(chosenAttack) {
            case 0: 
                trace("error");
                break;
            case BASICATTACK:
                basicAttack(target);
                break;
        }
    }

public function basicAttack(target:Character):void {
        target.loseHealth(strength);
        trace("Health: " + target.getHealth());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would still love a detailed description of exactly how stopImmediatePropagation and stopPropagation work, but I realized what my problem with this specific code is. The initial mouseClick was firing a CustomEvent, which is what got passed to setDice. So when I called stopImmediatePropagation in setDice, it was calling it on my customEvent. By adding it to the function which dispatched the custom event, it worked fine.

Comment: The way I approach software design is to have an intermediate "translator" that dispatches custom events for all or at least most system events, and then I listen for those. Then I just stop or start dispatching those custom events. That way, code in one place doesn't depend on code in another place to stop propagation, which can get dicey in a large system.